# Integrating Azure Application Gateway, AGIC and Istio

Tags: azure-aks, istio, azure-application-gateway

Was anyone able to integrate the three in the subject to achive end-2-end TLS?  To clarify, I'm talking about TLS between Application Gateway and Istio  ingress.
There are some threads on StackOverflow and there is an old issue on [AGIC Github repo](https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/issues/875#issuecomment-652464080)  but i was not able to find any evidence it's really working. If someone have it working, can you share the setup?

Comment: Hey @Sirtow had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

•   According to the Istio documentation, any request to the gateway will have two connections, viz., client downstream inbound connection to the gateway and client outbound connection to the destination as shown in the figure below: -

[image: TLS application gateway]

Thus, in the above scenario, consider the gateway as the Azure application gateway and the Istio ingress as the destination, as a result both these connections are independent TLS connections.

For TLS connections, there are a few more options:

a)  What protocol is encapsulated? If the connection is **HTTPS**, the server protocol should be configured as HTTPS. Otherwise, for a raw TCP connection encapsulated with TLS, the protocol should be set to TLS.

b)  Is the TLS connection terminated or passed through? For **passthrough traffic**, configure the TLS mode field to **PASSTHROUGH** : -

```
  apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
    kind: Gateway
           ...
       servers:
       - port:
         number: 443
           name: https
           protocol: HTTPS
         tls:
           mode: PASSTHROUGH
```

In this mode, Istio will route based on **SNI information** and forward the connection as-is to the destination. Mutual TLS can be configured through the TLS mode **MUTUAL**. When this is configured, **a client certificate** will be requested and verified against the configured **caCertificates** or **credentialName** : -

```
   apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
     kind: Gateway
      ...
       servers:
       - port:
         number: 443
           name: https
         protocol: HTTPS
         tls:
          mode: MUTUAL
          caCertificates: ... ’
```

The only difference is that you should be careful to consider the Gateway settings when configuring this. For example, if the Gateway is configured with TLS **PASSTHROUGH** while the **DestinationRule** configures TLS origination, you will end up with ***double encryption***. This works but is often not the desired behavior.

A **VirtualService** bound to the gateway needs care as well to ensure it is consistent with the Gateway definition. In this scenario, consider the gateway as an Azure application gateway in that sense the TLS settings are configured correctly. For more information, kindly refer to the Istio documentation below: -

https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/configuration/traffic-management/tls-configuration/

https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-sni-passthrough/